# "Error in cbind(x$CCA$v, x$CA$v) : number of rows of matrices must match (see arg 2)" when trying to plot capscale

Tags: r, plot, vegan

I am analysing microbial communities by constrained ordination (RDA, CCA and CAP) using the tables with environmental variables (soil properties).

The first block was 29 samples and 43 environmental variables. I used that code:

```
#Prokaryotes
#area

setwd("~/Cadmium/Cd_2022/Cd_R_2022")
Area.prok.spe <- read.delim ('Cadmium_Prok_otutab_area.txt', row.names = 1)
Area.prok.spe <- t(Area.prok.spe)
Area.prok.env <- read.delim ('Area_chem_prok.txt', row.names = 1)

# DCA
DCA <- decorana (log1p (Area.prok.spe))
DCA
# DCA1<3 => linear

#RDA
rda.area.prok <- rda (Area.prok.spe ~ ., data = Area.prok.env)
rda.area.prok
anova (rda.area.prok)
plot(rda.area.prok, type="text", xlim = c(- 5, 5), ylim = c(-10,10))
#No residual component(
ordistep(rda(Area.prok.spe ~ 1, data = Area.prok.env), scope=formula(rda.area.prok), direction="forward", pstep=1000)
ordistep.prok.A <- ordistep(rda(Area.prok.spe ~ 1, data = Area.prok.env), scope=formula(rda.area.prok), direction = "both", Pin = 0.05, Pout = 0.1, permutations = how(nperm = 999), steps = 50, trace = TRUE)
# look at the significant variables
ordistep.prok.A$anova
plot(ordistep.prok.A, type="text")
#Now we can calculate variations explained by individual fractions (using varpart function): 
varp <- varpart (Area.prok.spe,  ~ Feox, ~ Cat, ~ Cd, ~ Cdt, data = Area.prok.env)
varp
plot (varp, digits = 2, Xnames = c('Feox', 'Cat', 'Cd(CaCl2)', 'Cdt'), bg = c('navy', 'tomato', 'yellow', 'green'), cutoff = -1)

#CCA
Cd_cca_area <- cca(Area.prok.spe ~ ., Area.prok.env)
Cd_cca_area
anova.cca(Cd_cca_area, step=1000)
plot(Cd_cca_area, type="text")
ordistep.prok.A2 <- ordistep(cca(Area.prok.spe ~ 1, data=Area.prok.env), scope=formula(Area.prok.env), direction="forward", pstep=1000)
plot(ordistep.prok.A2, type="text")
ordistep.prok.A2$anova
varp.cca <- varpart (Area.prok.spe,  ~ Cdt, ~ K, ~ Be, ~ Cox, data = Area.prok.env)
varp.cca
plot (varp.cca, digits = 2, Xnames = c('Cdt', 'K (CaCl2)', 'Be(CaCl2)', 'Cox'), bg = c('navy', 'tomato', 'yellow', 'green'), cutoff = -1)


#CAP
cap_area <- capscale(Area.prok.spe ~ ., Area.prok.env, dist="bray")
Cd_cap_area
anova(Cd_cap_area)
plot(cap_area, type="text")
ordistep.prok.A3 <- ordistep(capscale(Area.prok.spe ~ 1, data=Area.prok.env), scope=formula(Cd_cap_area), direction="forward", pstep=1000)
ordistep.prok.A3$anova
plot(ordistep.prok.A3, type="text")
#anova(Cd_cap_area, by="axis", step=1000)
#anova(Cd_cap_area, by="terms", step=1000)
plot(capscale(Area.prok.spe ~ ., Area.prok.env, dist="bray"), type="text")
```

`plot(rda.area.prok, type="text", xlim = c(- 5, 5), ylim = c(-10,10))` and `plot(Cd_cca_area, type="text")` returned normal plots with environmental vectors. However, `plot(cap_area, type="text")` returns an error.

```
> plot(cap_area, type="text")
Error in cbind(x$CCA$v, x$CA$v) : 
  number of rows of matrices must match (see arg 2)
```

I checked if in both matrices there are 29 rows. They are. Of course. If there would be different number of rows, capscale wouldn't work from the first place. But the problem is only with the plot. That's ridiculous.

My second block of data was 31 samples and 55 environmental variables.

```
#Prokaryotes
#Profile A

setwd("~/Cadmium/Cd_2022/Cd_R_2022")
A.prok.spe <- read.delim ('Cadmium_Prok_otutab_A.txt', row.names = 1)
A.prok.spe <- t(A.prok.spe)
A.prok.env <- read.delim ('Cd_chem_A3.txt', row.names = 1)

# DCA
DCA <- decorana (log1p (A.prok.spe))
DCA
# DCA1<3 => linear

#RDA
rda.all <- rda (A.prok.spe ~ ., data = A.prok.env)
rda.all
anova (rda.all, step=1000)


ordistep.prok.A <- ordistep(rda(A.prok.spe ~ 1, data = A.prok.env), scope=formula(rda.all), direction="forward", pstep=1000)
# look at the significant variables
ordistep.prok.A$anova
plot(ordistep.prok.A, type="text")
#Now we can calculate variations explained by individual fractions (using varpart function): 
varp <- varpart (A.prok.spe,  ~ Feox, ~ Cat, ~ Cd, ~ Cdt, data = A.prok.env)
varp
plot (varp, digits = 2, Xnames = c('Feox', 'Cat', 'Cd(CaCl2)', 'Cdt'), bg = c('navy', 'tomato', 'yellow', 'green'), cutoff = -1)
plot(rda.all, type="text")

#CCA
Cd_cca_prokA <- cca(A.prok.spe ~ ., A.prok.env)
Cd_cca_prokA
anova.cca(Cd_cca_prokA, step=1000)
ordistep.prok.A2 <- ordistep(cca(A.prok.spe ~ 1, data=A.prok.env), scope=formula(A.prok.env), direction="forward", pstep=1000)
plot(ordistep.prok.A2, type="text")
plot(Cd_cca_prokA, type="text")
ordistep.prok.A2$anova
varp.cca <- varpart (A.prok.spe,  ~ Nit, ~ Crt, ~ VWC, ~ Cu + Cut, data = A.prok.env)
varp.cca
plot (varp.cca, digits = 2, Xnames = c('Nit', 'Crt', 'VWC', 'Cut + Cu(CaCl2)'), bg = c('navy', 'tomato', 'yellow', 'green'), cutoff = -1)

#CAP
Cd_cap_A <- capscale(A.prok.spe ~ ., A.prok.env, dist="bray")
Cd_cap_A
anova(Cd_cap_A)
ordistep.prok.A3 <- ordistep(capscale(A.prok.spe ~ 1, data=A.prok.env, dist="bray"), scope=formula(Cd_cap_A), direction="forward", pstep=1000)
ordistep.prok.A3$anova
plot(ordistep.prok.A3, type="text")
plot(Cd_cap_A, type="text")
anova(Cd_cap_A, by="axis", step=1000)
anova_cap_A_terms <- anova(Cd_cap_A, by="terms", step=1000)
```

I used the same code and everything was very similar, but `plot(Cd_cap_A, type="text")` worked fine.

Why did I failed to make a plot in the first block?

Thank you.

Comment: Plenty of code, most of which works and is useless for the problem. However, I fail to see `cap_area` anywhere before you say it caused an error in `plot(cap_area, type = "text")`. Please prune your example so that it *shows* the problem, and *nothing but* the problem. Now I'm just clueless.

Comment: Hi!
I added "nothing but the problem" as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Please prune your example so that it shows the problem, and nothing but the problem.

```
cap_area <- capscale(Area.prok.spe ~ ., Area.prok.env, dist="bray")
cap_area
plot(cap_area, type="text")
```

returns

```
> plot(cap_area, type="text")
Error in cbind(x$CCA$v, x$CA$v) : 
  number of rows of matrices must match (see arg 2)
```

Comment: высоко уважаемая коллега, still no reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

The error appears only when >27 variables are used.

```
> plot(cap_area, type="text")
Error in cbind(x$CCA$v, x$CA$v) : 
  number of rows of matrices must match (see arg 2)
```

When

```
plot(capscale(Area.prok.spe ~ urtica + Alt + Ast + Bat + Cat + Cdt + Cot + Crt + Cut + Fet + Kt + Mgt + Mnt + Nat + Nit + Pbt + St + Sit + Znt + Cox + pHBaCl2 + CEC + BS + Alox + Feox + Mnox + Cdox, data = Area.prok.env, distance = "bray"), type="text")
```

it returns plot.